# Sum two values from 2 different divs not working

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Im beginner at JS and I have stucked on this problem.
I have tried and read on google and other people with almost same issue but I cant make this work.

```
 var start = 0;
 // Add number
var total = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += start;
document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = total;
```

That code is in a button click function.
The value start at 0.
And every time press the button, the value from div1 is + in divResult.

so if div1 contain the value 10 then divResult should be +10 every time button is pressed.
The value in div1 is dynamic.

Now that code just do "101001010010" Just keeps adding 1 and 0 when press the button.

Comment: `var total = document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += start;` what this line is doing?

Comment: total = value of div1 + start

and start is 0

Comment: something + 0 = something

Comment: Hey @hollowman, try to edit the post making the code functional to let you show the changes proposed easily.

Comment: parse the initial value within the div then sum and instert  `var total =  parseInt(document.getElementById('div1').text) + start; document.getElementById('divResult').innerHTML = total;`

Comment: Slim, that code gave me "NaN" as result.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="value">10</p>
<p id="result">Result</p>

<button id="myBtn">Add</button>


<script>
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
var total  = 0
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('value').innerHTML;
  total = +total + +x
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = total
}
</script>

</body>
</html>`

Answer (score -1):

You have to wrap the `innerHTML` into `Number()` or `parseInt()` depending on your case.

[Here](https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/) you have a post could help understand better how to convert *strings* into *Numbers* in JavaScript.